# How to find selector for this HTML snippet

Tags: python, selenium

How to find selector from this? I want to click the button but unable to find selector.it will be a css selector or class selector.

HTML

```
<button data-bb-handler="confirm" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Continue and Logout Other User</button>
```

Comment: Could you show the page or the XPATh, CSS selector too ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it

```
button_Login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#button").text("Continue and Logout Other User")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the button is visible when you try to click it.
The following selectors should work:

```
.btn-succes 
//button[@class='btn btn-succes']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following selectors -

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button.btn.btn-success')

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'button[class='btn btn-success']')

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[normalize-space()='Continue and Logout Other User']")
```

Comment: If my answer helped you to solve the issue, please mark this answer as accepted answer.